# Ubuntu autoinstall with TPM2/LUKS auto-decrypt

Tags: encryption, luks

I'm deploying Ubuntu 20.04 using the new autoinstall method. My deployment process works and we are encrypting the root volume with LUKS.

I wan't to setup auto-decryption of the root volume on boot using TPM2 and Clevis. I can successfully configure this manually after deployment with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# LUKS Bind - Enroll LUKS key with TPM for full-disk encryption
apt-get install clevis clevis-tpm2 clevis-luks clevis-initramfs initramfs-tools
clevis luks bind -d /dev/nvme0n1p3 tpm2 '{"pcr_bank":"sha256"}' <<< 'luks_passphrase'
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

However, I wan't this step to run as a late-command in the autoinstall phase, before the system reboots and avoid ever having to manually input the LUKS passphrase.

The script runs successfully during deployment, and I can see the clevis TPM pin has been installed, however, auto-decrypt still does not work.

```
$ sudo clevis luks list -d /dev/nvme0n1p3
    1: tpm2 '{"hash":"sha256","key":"ecc","pcr_bank":"sha256","pcr_ids":"7"}'
```

If I unbind the clevis pin after deployment, then re-run the script above, everything works fine.

So I'm not sure what is causing the issue. I have tried removing the pcr_ids parameters and with secure-boot on and off.

Answer (score 0):

I am myself struggling with this. I am guessing (correct me if I am wrong) that there are 2 reasons why this is not possible like this:

1. During the deployment/autoinstall, you are running in the live ubuntu environment. When you add the key to TPM, I am guessing it is sealed with the current boot/BIOS config (depending on the PCRs used). When booting in the installed OS, this will not match with the PCRs and the key will not be unsealed.
2. When running the clevis/update-initramfs, you are actually updating the initram image of the live environment, not the one of the installed OS. Not sure if it is possible to (easily) update the installed OS's initram.

My thought was to create a custom ubuntu installation medium with an updated initram image which can decrypt a luks volume using a predefiend keyfile also on the installation medium. Then using the runcmd in the autoinstall, running a script on firstboot that will setup the TPM and replace the current key of the luks volume with the one in the TPM.

Comment: If you don't care about the PCRs, you could probably just chroot into the installed OS (mounted at /target during deployment) and update the initramfs. Just keep in mind that that would also kind of defeat the purpose of sealing the key/pin in the TMP because you could just boot a livecd or some other OS and just get the key from the TPM. That is what the PCRs are for to prevent releasing the key if the boot process has changed.